Switching smart contract data from Polygon testnet to Amoy testnet
I developed a smart contract and put it on the Polygon Mumbai testnet; all of my project data is now stored on the Polygon testnet, and I wish to switch to the Amoy testnet. Is it possible to acquire all the data held on smart contracts located on the Polygon testnet by switching to the Amoy testnet?
I want to fetch Smart contract data of deprecated Testnet by switching to different testnet
